# Set a certain range of textboxes to be invisible (vb)

Tags: vb.net, loops

I am relatively new to VB.net and I would like to hide all textboxes that are not in a certain value. My textboxes' IDs are from 1-30 (e.g. TextBox1, TextBox2, ...).

An example of my problem is this:

If the length of a string is 7 -> hide TextBoxes from 8-30 (leave only 7 textboxes).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the textboxes to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i=8 to 30
            Dim c as string = "Textbox" & i.toString
            DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(c, False)(0), TextBox).Enabled= False
Next
```

Let's cycle between 8 and 30, create a string c containing the control name by combining "textbox" and i.
Find the control whose name is c among the controls in the form, do not recurse, and select the first occurrence (0). Set the property of such control to Enabled = false.

Comment: Didn't answer my question: how do I make an element invisible?

Comment: I'm so sorry I disappointed you. What about the .visible property?

Comment: I'm so sincerely sorry that my comment sounded condescending. Since I'm new to VB, please can you describe where to put the .visible?

Comment: In place of .enabled

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

It loops through all controls (of type `TextBox`) on a `Form`.

Replaces the text "textbox" in the control-name and tries to parse the rest (the textbox-number) to an `Integer`.

If it can be parsed to a number then the `Visible`-property of the textbox is set to `True` or `False`, depending on the value of the `num` variable and the textbox-number.

```
Sub SetTextboxVisibility(num As Integer)
    Dim tbNumber As Integer

    For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        If Integer.TryParse(tb.Name.ToUpper.Replace("TEXTBOX", ""), tbNumber) Then
            tb.Visible = tbNumber <= num
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

To show the first 7 Textboxes

```
SetTextboxVisibility(7)
```

Comment: don't like it, and no comments given to the code. Also does not solve the problem of the OP. This sub is not able to change visibility of textboxes from 8 to 30, but only from 1 to 7. Downvoted.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli Comments added (BTW `don't like it` is no downvote reason) **and** it leaves textboxes 1 to 7 visible and hides 8 to 30 like OP wanted.

Comment: Upvoted, though still the approach is IMHO incorrect. You solved the complementary problem, not the problem itself. In case the OP wants to change visibility of say 5 to 15, your sub does not provide a solution.

Comment: There's only mentioned one example to hide textboxes from 1 to 7 because of the length 7 of a string. So if the length is 12, then only textbox 1 to 12 should be visible. At least thats what I understood. So IMHO this does exactly solve OP's problem an not the complementary.